# How to make 2 characters be seen as one letter?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, character, alphabet

I'm creating a game which will be in the Welsh language. Purpose of the game is to help children learn to spell certain words. So basically when a word is spoken out, they have to spell the word by clicking the correct letters on the screen.

The challenge I have is comparing the characters of the word to the letter they've chosen. They will obviously have to choose the letters in the correct order. As the Welsh alphabet contains **8 letters** that have **2 characters** each i.e. `Ch, Dd, Ll etc`, the compiler will read them as separate characters i.e. `'C'` instead of `'Ch'`. An example would be the word `'Gwallt' (hair in English)`. The compiler will think the L's are 2 separate occurrences of the letter L. In fact it's one letter in Welsh.... So when the user clicks `'Ll'` on the screen for its spelling it would throw an error.... how could I avoid this? Is there some rule I could set up? I have all the various words being stored in an array. Hope the above made any sense?

Comment: do you have access to the whole string or character per character?

Comment: I have the whole string in an array. For example, there's 10 words in the array, thus 10 string elements. Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by character by character?

Answer (score 1):

A split with a Regex may help you.

```
//ch is the first element, ll an other char or any char from a to z
//Ignoring case and multi line
private Regex tokenizerRegex = new Regex(@"(ch|ll|[a-z])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
//split your input string
//split returns an array of strings
var tokensText = tokenizerRegex.Split("channel");
//print results
tokensText.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
```

Result:

```
> empty string
> ch
> empty string
> a
> empty string
> n
> empty string
> n
> empty string
> e
> empty string
> l
> empty string
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. How would I though compare a character of the word (e.g Ch) to the button letter clicked (e.g Ch)? Would it regard 'Ch' as being two separate letters instead of one?

Comment: Ow! I think I'm beginning to see it! So if you gave it the string 'Chemistry' it would also realise that the Ch is one letter/character?

Comment: Would it be possible for me to pass a string array (which holds the Welsh alphabet) to the Regex function?

Comment: yes, sure, just iterate them with a `for` loop and returns a matrix of char

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the character encoding. I would advise using the correct Unicode code point for the specific digraphs
[.NET Character Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding#selecting-an-encoding-class)
[Latin Script in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode)

Comment: Thank you for that. I don't know what would be the correct Unicode code point would be though :/ would there even be a Unicode for Welsh alphabet letters such as 'Ch', 'Dd', 'Ll' etc?